# do... while(0) define block and support for type cast

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, user-defined-functions

What is the correct macro to support code block and still be tolerant to type casting?

```
if (fooisneeded)
    (void)foo();
```

`#define foo() do {foo_subpart1(); foo_subpart2;} while(0)`: will not tolerate type cast

`#define foo() 0; do {foo_subpart1(); foo_subpart2;} while(0)`: will break in braceless `if`/`<loop>`

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you post a full code snippet?

Comment: What is the point of casting the return value of a function to `void`? Can't you just call the function and ignore the return value?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage it can be used to remove unused variable warning, but i don't know if it is what op is try to do

Comment: @squeamishossifrage is do not control how the user will call the function. The use case is OSEK OS, and return the function is (void)TerminateTask(). This usually comes from overzealous but very common customer requirement

Comment: Why do you want a macro?

Comment: @Mat for performance and curiosity (tbh)

Comment: @Tyker Yes, that is the point, and it is not nitpicking, is a legit and common customer requirement

Comment: Do you actually need the `do{}while(0)` (or for `foo` to be a macro in the first place?)  What goes inside the curlies?

Comment: @PSkocik I have added clarification to the case. `do {} while(0)` is used to run a code block as a single expression and still accept a semicolon when used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `(void) foo()` is just not possible with macros because that construct relies on a return type, which a macro, by its very nature, does not have. Neither does a macro have knowledge about C semantics or syntax, so computing a return type is impossible already.

What's the point anyway? Casting function expressions to `(void)` is intended to tell the compiler "you ain't gonna need it." A macro does not even return a value, it just does textual substitution. You ain't gonna need the "you ain't gonna need it."

Use an `inline` function instead or just a function. If you need to do this sort of stuff, then macros are the wrong tool.

Comment: Or `static inline` function. In my experience results with `inline` are a bit flakey, but compilers undestand to optimize `static` better, as the linkage of function is limited.

Comment: `inline` on it's own is completely pointless. It only hints to the compiler that you might want to inline this function. The compiler doesn't have to inline it. In fact it must still provide the code for the function in case it's called from another compilation unit. So most compilers simply ignore it outright and have their own heuristic when to inline. Using `inline` in a header file causes duplicate symbols later on. Only the combination of `static inline` gives it useful meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Nonstandardly, if it needs to be a macro, you can use the statements-as-expression
extension (available at least with gcc,  tcc, and clang)

```
#define foo() ({ for(;;);  }) 
//equivalent to a func returning void or whatever the type of
//the last statement before }) is
int main()
{
    (void)foo();
}
```

Otherwise, there's void inline/static functions.